# can not install using sdk on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, sdkman

I tried to install gradle using sdk, but it failed, and I have no idea why

```
sdk install gradle 6.2

Downloading: gradle 6.2

In progress...

Warning: Failed to create the file /home/nydia/.sdkman/tmp/gradle-6.2.bin: No
Warning: such file or directory

curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 8602)
mv: cannot stat '/home/nydia/.sdkman/tmp/gradle-6.2.bin': No such file or directory
```

I saw a similar question, he solved with add curl on cygwin package, but I already got curl on cygwin. I'm not sure why it still not work. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Gradle requires Java and Cygwin has not a Java machine, so you need to use a Windows Java machine. I do not see the added value to install Gradle from Cygwin

Comment: Thanks. Apparently you just need curl to get past this error. Also restarting cygwin after installing curl works for me.